# How do I create tests in TFS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, testing, tfs

I am new to TFS and have been working through the functionality with a test app that I have developed. I am onto the testing stage but I can't find a way to create test plans or add any functionality.

I get onto the test home page below but don't know how to move on with creating a plan.[image: Test home page]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you think about un product like HP-QC I think you need a Visual Studio 
Test Professional or Visual Studio Entreprise and you'll have access of this features in TFS with the associate licences

Comment: I am using VS professional.

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to install the test manager extension for your account to create/manage test plans on the web. Today this functionality is not available with VS Professional without MSDN

See [this link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web&utm_source=vsts%20XT&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=vsts%20XT%20tip) for more details

You can also enable a 90-day account-wide trial for the test manager features by going to your `https://account.visualstudio.com/_admin/_home/settings`
and enabling the `Account-wide Test Manager trial`

Comment: Makes sense Thanks Allen!

Comment: @Andrew mark the answer if it has addressed your question. Would also like to remind you that SO rules state that we avoid salutations and other pleasantries to drive better focus.